# Fetch data from 1 Google Analytics account to another

Tags: google-analytics

I have 2 Google Analytics accounts for 2 pages on my website.  While my users view content on 1 page, they migrate and sign up finally on the other. I want to see all this data (page visit and conversion) on 1 panel to be able to analyse how my website is performing. How can I do that?

Comment: Easiest way would be to use Google Data Studio (available for free) and create two data sources (on for each account). While you cannot mix data from two sources in one widget (graph or data table) you can at least look at data from both sources in a single report. I am not sure this is quite on topic, though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot merge Two account's (only properties for GA360 users)
You can:
a. send both pages into the same property and keep 3 views:
   1 - only landing page
   2 - only app
   3 - all data
b. use the dataStudio (as Eike Pierstorff offered)